# Loading a keras model with custom loss based on input

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a custom loss which uses one of the inputs to the model.

```
def closs(labels,latent_dim):
  def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return metric_learning.contrastive_loss(labels=labels,
                        embeddings_anchor=y_pred[:,:latent_dim],
                        embeddings_positive=y_pred[:,latent_dim:])
return loss
```

Where labels is an input to the model. The model architecture is:

```
def build_model():
  left_input = Input(shape=(2900,1))
  right_input = Input(shape=(2900,1))
  label = Input(shape=(1,))

  encoder = build_encoder()

  left_embed = encoder(left_input)
  right_embed = encoder(right_input)

  embeds = Concatenate()([left_embed,right_embed])

  model = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input,label],outputs=[embeds])
  return model, label
```

Then I use the returned "label" to compile the model:

```
model,label = build_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=closs(label,256))
```

But when I try to load the model, I have to pass this loss as a custom_object, so something like this:

```
model = load_model('model/cl_model.h5',custom_objects={'loss':closs(xyz,256)})
```

The issue is that I'm loading the model in a different python script, and so I don't have the "label" input object. 
How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the weights to retrain the model or just to predict on new data?
In the case of only-predicting you could just use

```py
model.load_weights('model/cl_model.h5')
```

after defining your model, you won't have to pass  the loss function since it's only used to predict.

Comment: I wanted to retrain the model